# iOS - Push notifications, SSL error connecting to Apple APNS server

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

My push notifications have been working fine for months, but have suddenly stopped being able to connect to the Apple APNS server with the following error :

Error connecting with SSL.  error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

I've checked the following on my service :

1. Path to the .pem file is correct - Yes
2. Server can Telnet to gateway.push.apple.com on port 2195 - Yes
3. .pem file has not expired - Yes
4. .pem passphrase is correct - Yes

The only thing I can think of is that the iOS provisioning profile for the app expired 4 weeks ago and I hadn't got round to renewing it, as I haven't got any app updates planned.  I've now just renewed it but am still getting the SSL errors.  If the provisioning profile expires will it block the use of APNS for the app?  I wouldn't have thought they are related.  My APNS certificate doesn't expire for another 10 months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorted it - I missed the news that Apple dropped support for SSLv3.0 on their APNS servers on October 29th 2014.  I've updated my service to connect with TLSv1.0 instead and all is working again.

Will have to read the Apple Developer site more often :

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10222014a